# App not compatible with any devices on Google play

Tags: android, apk

Loaded my apk file on Google play only to find that it is not compatible with any device.  In the manifest file I support all screen sizes, build grade has a minimum sdk level of 15 and a target sdk level of 21.

The Apk file downloads on on my phone and tablet when loaded to Google drive. Nor sure if any one can help. 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId 
 "com.songbook.noo.sttrfsongbook"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.1"
     }
     buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles    
getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-   
android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
 }

  dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs',      
 include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 
 'com.android.support:appcompat-   
 v7:22.1.1'
     compile     





'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
```

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'
    compile 
     'com.google.android.gms:play- 
    services-ads:7.5.0'
    }

Comment: which platform you are develop android app,Android studio ya Eclips. and show build.gridle file code

Comment: Can you post build.gradle + manifest?

Comment: Android studio, vuild gradle added to main question